# Regex and replace selected results only

Tags: regex, text, editing, corpus

I want to know whether there is any tool that does a regex search across huge text (xml or tagged or html) and replace only the cases which are selected across shown (should have 'select/deselect/select all' options while applying the replace regex).

Like the below example:

My content is:

```
"Visited xtreme.com, stupid.net, childish.com, happy.net and innocence.edu. There are some cross.network isssues that are to be fixed."
```

Now in this content, i want to replace all ".net" occurrences with ".com" and so a simple tool like notepad++ would replace it easily. But i want the tool to show the search results and give the option to replace only first two occurrences of ".net" and not the instance in "cross.network"

This is only example purposes only and don't suggest an alternate regex. I don't need it.

Comment: You can use a word boundary `\.net\b` to select/replace only those not having word characters at the end by use of regex. Dunno if there's any *first two* in np++ but you can just click on "Find Next" and click "Replace" if that match should be replaced.

Comment: The above example is only for understanding purposes. I don't need an alternative regex. NP++ is good with "Find Next" option, but it is not sufficient with huge data with more than 1000+ occurrences.

Comment: you can try the tools like AstroGrep and DocFetcher

Answer (score 1):

NP++ or sublime are all fine, as long as they can read all the text to the memory. They both support regexes for finding and replacing text.

If the text files are too big, i.e. NP++ crashes, then you can use `sed`. It's a command line tool that can replace text like this:

```
sed -i filename.txt 's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

On windows boxes you need [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) or [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor like `sublime` and apply a **word boundary** to the regular expression:

```
\.net\b
```

This will find `.net` in `stupid.net` but not in `cross.network`.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vB9lV6/1).